# Searching for Windows Forms DataGrid (incl. commercial) with specific requirements

Tags: .net, winforms, gridview, datagrid

I know, there were multiple questions like this, but I have some special requirements, which I would like the grid to meet. Meeting all is not necessary, but at least some would be nice (ordered by priority):

1. Connection to custom datasource (preferably via some simple interface instead of queryable)
2. Built-in paging
3. Built-in filtering
4. Built-in grouping
5. Built-in sorting
6. Paging and filtering exposed via interface (i.e. LoadPage(limit, offset, sort,...) -- you know, what I mean).

Is there something like this? I've checked PFGrid (no paging), DevExpress (too complicated to implement), default DataGridView (slow, no paging, no grouping).

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered something like Infragistics? http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/grid/

It has most of the features you have requested above I believe. However the learning curve with custom controls can be quite steep until you get used to how things work.

Comment: @53AN Thank you, I'm going to check it out. It's even more expensive then DevExpress, but if it would fit the requirements...

Answer (score 0):

The grids provided by Infragistics or Telerik both match all your requirements, though I'm not entirely sure about the last one.

Telerik: http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/gridview.aspx

Infragistics: http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/grid/